# Python multiprocessing: Why don't objects instances have the same adress?

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I'm wondering why the child processes print out different object addresses. I've also tried with a manager but it doesn't affect the result.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

class TestO:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def get_name(self):
        return self.a



def run_task(tasks,nr):
    obj = tasks[nr]['data']
    print obj, obj.get_name()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    tasks = dict()

    a = TestO('first')
    b = TestO('second')

    tasks[1] = {'data': a}
    tasks[2] = {'data': b}


    process1 = mp.Process(target = run_task, name = 'process1', args = (tasks, 1))
    process2 = mp.Process(target = run_task, name = 'process2', args = (tasks, 2))

    process1.start()

    time.sleep(0.2)

    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()


    print a, 'first'
    print b, 'second'
```

This will give the result

```
<__main__.TestO instance at 0x02EFD2D8> first
<__main__.TestO instance at 0x0373D300> second
<__main__.TestO instance at 0x043663C8> first
<__main__.TestO instance at 0x043663F0> second
```

Are the instances being copied? Is there a way to keep the same instance somehow? I'm having trouble with a more complex version of the above where the class objects are more complex. The result I get in that case is that the values I set on the object instances are nullified after they enter `mp.Process`, i.e. `obj.get_name` returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spawning multiple processes.  Thanks to the magic of virtual memory, you cannot (must not) expect two different processes to have the same addresses at all.

As to your question:

> Is there a way to keep the same instance somehow?

Not really, because you are starting separate processes.  Though if you insist, you could use "shared memory" to share a single instance of a data structure between processes.

Comment: How would I got about using shared memory with the example I provided? I thought using a manager would be the same as shared memory, but I get different addresses in that case as well.

Comment: I could be mistaken but since the GIL prevents real shared memory, aren't the arguments to `mp.Process` serialized?

Comment: @Chicony: If you use a Manager you can get sharing, but the addresses will still be different because of "virtual memory."  Read up on virtual memory and you will see.  Just because two things live at two different virtual addresses doesn't tell you if they are the same instance, when you're talking about two different processes.